# vim Jump to the next non-identical line

Tags: vim

I am looking at files that may have several consecutive identical lines.

Is there a easy way of jumping to the next non-identical line?

Alternatively I would like to be able to fold all the lines that are equal to the initial one showing just the number of linees that are folded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define your own fold-expr:

first set fdm:

```
:set fdm=expr
```

then

```
:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)==#getline(v:lnum-1)?1:0
```

now you can test by typing <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, to close all fold, if you are lucky ^_^ all duplicated lines are folded.

you could type <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to open all folds.

if it works and you open those kind of file very often, you could put the above lines in your .vimrc.(au with ft) if only one time job, you can write mode line into that file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  :nmap <F2> "1y$<CR>/^\(<C-R>1$\)\@!<CR>
```

It maps F2 to:

- copy the current line into register 1
- search for (and move to) the first line that does not match the contents of register 1

This seems to work well, unless the text of your copied line has escaped characters that will confuse the search regexp. This is because register 1 is just dropped into the search expression without escaping. This would be tricky to fix reliably, but for normal log files, it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Also: if you're not married to vim and just need to read the non-consecutively-duplicated lines of a file, the canonical UNIX way is:

```
uniq filename
```

If you want to be in vim but won't need to make changes to the file, try:

```
:%!uniq
```

(If you try the latter, be sure to exit without saving)

Comment: the first idea is nice. the `uniq` is too dangerous...if user did some changes and then want to skip dups or skip dups and want to do some changes....